# How to decompress/deflate PDF Stream

Tags: pdf, go, gzip, zlib

Working with the `2016-W4 pdf`, which has 2 large streams *(page 1 & 2)*, along with a bunch of other objects and smaller streams. I'm trying to deflate the stream(s), to work with the source data, but am struggling. I'm only able to get corrupt inputs and invalid checksums errors.

I've written a test script to help debug, and have pulled out smaller streams from the file to test with.

Here are 2 streams from the original pdf, along with their length objects:

**stream 1**:

```
149 0 obj
<< /Length 150 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode /Type /XObject /Subtype /Form /FormType
1 /BBox [0 0 8 8] /Resources 151 0 R >>
stream
x+TT(T0�B ,JUWÈS0Ð37±402V(NFJS�þ¶
«
endstream
endobj
150 0 obj
42
endobj
```

***stream 2***

```
142 0 obj
<< /Length 143 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode /Type /XObject /Subtype /Form /FormType
1 /BBox [0 0 0 0] /Resources 144 0 R >>
stream
x+T�ç�ã
endstream
endobj
143 0 obj
11
endobj
```

I copied just the `stream` contents into new files within Vim *(excluding the carriage returns after `stream` and before `endstream`)*.

I've tried both:

- `compress/flate` *([rfc-1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951)) – (removing the first 2 bytes (`CMF`, `FLG`))*
- `compress/zlib` *([rfc-1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950))*

I've converted the streams to `[]byte` for the below:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/flate"
    "compress/gzip"
    "compress/zlib"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

var (
    flateReaderFn = func(r io.Reader) (io.ReadCloser, error) { return flate.NewReader(r), nil }
    zlibReaderFn  = func(r io.Reader) (io.ReadCloser, error) { return zlib.NewReader(r) }
)

func deflate(b []byte, skip, length int, newReader func(io.Reader) (io.ReadCloser, error)) {
    // rfc-1950
    // --------
    //   First 2 bytes
    //   [120, 1] - CMF, FLG
    //
    //   CMF: 120
    //     0111 1000
    //     ↑    ↑
    //     |    CM(8) = deflate compression method
    //     CINFO(7)   = 32k LZ77 window size
    //
    //   FLG: 1
    //     0001 ← FCHECK
    //            (CMF*256 + FLG) % 31 == 0
    //             120 * 256 + 1 = 30721
    //                             30721 % 31 == 0

    stream := bytes.NewReader(b[skip:length])
    r, err := newReader(stream)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("\nfailed to create reader,", err)
        return
    }

    n, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)
    if err != nil {
        if n > 0 {
            fmt.Print("\n")
        }
        fmt.Println("\nfailed to write contents from reader,", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d bytes written\n", n)
    r.Close()
}

func main() {
    //readerFn, skip := flateReaderFn, 2 // compress/flate RFC-1951, ignore first 2 bytes
    readerFn, skip := zlibReaderFn, 0 // compress/zlib RFC-1950, ignore nothing

    //                                                                                                ⤹ This is where the error occurs: `flate: corrupt input before offset 19`.
    stream1 := []byte{120, 1, 43, 84, 8, 84, 40, 84, 48, 0, 66, 11, 32, 44, 74, 85, 8, 87, 195, 136, 83, 48, 195, 144, 51, 55, 194, 177, 52, 48, 50, 86, 40, 78, 70, 194, 150, 74, 83, 8, 4, 0, 195, 190, 194, 182, 10, 194, 171, 10}
    stream2 := []byte{120, 1, 43, 84, 8, 4, 0, 1, 195, 167, 0, 195, 163, 10}

    fmt.Println("----------------------------------------\nStream 1:")
    deflate(stream1, skip, 42, readerFn) // flate: corrupt input before offset 19

    fmt.Println("----------------------------------------\nStream 2:")
    deflate(stream2, skip, 11, readerFn) // invalid checksum
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong somewhere, I just can't quite see it.

*(The pdf does open in a viewer)*

Comment: Are you sure vim displayed you and copied the correct bytes? You should take the data from a hex editor (e.g. check [hecate](https://github.com/evanmiller/hecate)).

Comment: @icza - If you wanna post that as an answer, I'll give you the credit =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary data should *never* be copied out of / saved from text editors. There might be cases when this succeeds, and it just adds oil to the flame.

Your data that you eventually "mined out" from the PDF is most likely not identical to the actual data that *is* in the PDF. You should take the data from a hex editor (e.g. try [hecate](https://github.com/evanmiller/hecate) for something new), or write a simple app that saves it (which strictly handles the file as binary).

Hint #1:

The binary data displayed spread across multiple lines. Binary data does not contain carriage returns, that's a textual control. If it does, that means the editor *did* interpret it as text, and so some codes / characters where "consumed" to start a new line. Multiple sequences may be interpreted as the same newline (e.g. `\n`, `\r\n`). By excluding them, you're already at data loss, by including them, you might already have a different sequence. And if the data was  interpreted and displayed as text, more problems may arise as there are more control characters, and some characters may not appear when displayed.

Hint #2:

When `flateReaderFn` is used, decoding the 2nd example succeeds (completes without an error). This means "you were barking up the right tree", but the success depends on what the actual data is and to what extent was it "distorted" by the text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, confession time...

I was so caught up in trying to understand deflate that I completely overlooked the fact that Vim wasn't saving the stream contents correctly into new files. So I spent quite a bit of time reading the RFC's, and digging through the internals of the Go `compress/...` packages, assuming the problem was with my code.

Shortly after I posted my question I tried reading the PDF as a whole, finding the `stream`/`endstream` locations, and pushing that through deflate. As soon as I saw the content scroll through the screen I realized my dumb mistake.

+1 @icza, that was exactly my issue.

*It was good in then end, as I have a much better understanding of the whole process than if it would have just worked the first go around.*

Answer (score 0):

Extracting objects from PDF can be tricky depending on the filters used. The filter can also have additional options which need to be handled correctly.

For someone interested in extracting an object without taking care of the low-level details of the process.

To get a single object from a PDF and decode it can be done as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/unidoc/unipdf/v3/core"
    "github.com/unidoc/unipdf/v3/model"
)


func main() {
    objNum := 149 // Get object 149
    err := inspectPdfObject("input.pdf", objNum)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func inspectPdfObject(inputPath string, objNum int) error {
    f, err := os.Open(inputPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer f.Close()

    pdfReader, err := model.NewPdfReader(f)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    isEncrypted, err := pdfReader.IsEncrypted()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if isEncrypted {
        // If encrypted, try decrypting with an empty one.
        // Can also specify a user/owner password here by modifying the line below.
        auth, err := pdfReader.Decrypt([]byte(""))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Decryption error: %v\n", err)
            return err
        }
        if !auth {
            fmt.Println(" This file is encrypted with opening password. Modify the code to specify the password.")
            return nil
        }
    }

    obj, err := pdfReader.GetIndirectObjectByNumber(objNum)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Printf("Object %d: %s\n", objNum, obj.String())

    if stream, is := obj.(*core.PdfObjectStream); is {
        decoded, err := core.DecodeStream(stream)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        fmt.Printf("Decoded:\n%s", decoded)
    } else if indObj, is := obj.(*core.PdfIndirectObject); is {
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", indObj.PdfObject)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", indObj.PdfObject.String())
    }

    return nil
}
```

A full example: [pdf_get_object.go](https://github.com/unidoc/unipdf-examples/blob/master/analysis/pdf_get_object.go)

**Disclosure**: I am the original developer of UniPDF.